# App not running after installing using .APK generated via VSTS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am making a android app using Xamarin.Android. App is working when deployed via Visual Studio on the phone. It is also working when generating the Archive via Visual Studio and signing it.

Similarly I have configured a build in VSTS and project is getting correctly and then signed but when I am using the signed .apk after successful install of app when launched then app only white screen is appearing. No error nothing..

Build Definition 
[image]

App screenshot 
[image]

Comment: Can you share the detail build/release log on the OneDrive? (set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log) Can you reproduce this issue with a new project?

Comment: with @JamesMontemagno  suggestion I was finally able to solve the issue. The issue was because it was not doing zipalign in the build steps. Once I enabled it every thing worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the issue. The issue was because it was not doing zipalign in the build steps. Once I enabled it every thing worked fine

Comment: Thanks for that answer. It worked for me as well, although it was throwing at first exception 'ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set'. I've put it into build variables pointing to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk" and it helped :) (of course you can set up env variable permanently on agent box as well)